# Compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Are there any convenient ways to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix?

Comment: An easier but more or less equivalent problem is to compute the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A + 2I$.

Comment: Well, for a start, -2 is an eigenvalue, as $A+2I$ will have $n$ columns of all $2$s. In fact, this will mean the dimension of $\mathrm{Null}(A+2I)$ is $n-1$ (dimension of the column space is 1, then use the rank theorem), which leaves only one eigenvalue left to find.

Comment: The last eigenvalue is quite easy to find as well. By inspection $v = [1 \,\, 1 \,\, \cdots \,\, 1]^t$ is an eigenvector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One convenient way to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix is to use the fact that it is a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix). An $n \times n$ circulant matrix is any matrix of the form

[image: circulant matrix]

You can show that the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are of the form
\begin{align}
v_j &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left( 1, \omega_j, \cdots \omega_j^{n-1} \right)^T\\
\lambda_j &= \displaystyle \Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1} c_i \omega_j^{n-i} \\
\end{align}
for $j=0, \cdots n-1$ where $\omega_j = \exp \left(\frac{2 \pi i j}{n}\right)$. So using this fact, we can easily compute that the two eigenvalues of $A$ are $-2$ with multiplicity $n-1$ and $2(n-1)$ with multiplicity $1$. Again, using the properties of circulant matrices we get that the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda = 2(n-1)$ is $span( \mathbb{1})$ where $\mathbb{1}$ is the all-ones vector. And so the eignenspace for $\lambda = -2$ is the set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ orthogonal to $\mathbb{1}$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, observe that $A+2I$ has $n$ columns of all $2$s, which will make $\mathrm{dim ~ Null}(A+2I) = n-1$, showing that $-2$ is an eigenvalue as long as $n > 1$. (If $n = 1$, $A$ is the zero transformation which has only eigenvalue $0$).

We find the remaining eigenvalue next:

Consider the vector $ v = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Then matrix multiplication will show that: $Av = \begin{bmatrix} 2(n-1) \\ 2(n-1) \\ \vdots \\ 2(n-1) \end{bmatrix}$.

Observe that $Av = 2(n-1)v$, making $v$ an eigenvector with eigenvalue $2(n-1)$.

Since $\mathrm{dim} ~ E(-2, A) = n-1$, $\mathrm{dim} ~ E(2(n-1), A) = 1$,

We conclude that $A$ is diagonalizable and $E(2(n-1), A) = \mathrm{span}(v)$

We need only compute the eigenvectors associated with $-2$

For the purpose of (what I think is) ease of formatting, let $e_1, ... , e_n$ be the basis $A$ is written with respect to. Consider a vector of the form $w_k = e_1 - e_k$ for $k \in \{2, ..., n\}$. Then $A(e_1 - e_k) = 2e_2 + ... + 2e_n - (2e_1 + ... + 2e_{k-1} + 2e_{k+1} + ... + 2e_n) = -2e_1 + 2e_k$.

So each $w_k$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-2$

(and it is easy to see linear independence of the $w_k$'s).

Thus $E(-2, A) = \mathrm{span}(e_1 - e_2, e_1 - e_3, ... , e_1 - e_n)$, or, in alternate form:

$$\mathrm{span}\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots  \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} , ... , \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} \right)$$

Note: I came up with this solution by clever reasoning of which vectors would be eigenvectors. I wanted to include my answer as a possible method to the problem (and it does answer the question), but there is probably a more systematic method to approach this problem than these tricks.

Comment: Yeah, I think your method is suitable to use in an exam. But if we want to exploit a systematic method, using the fact of the circulant matrix(displayed in another answer) might be a good choice.

Comment: I agree; Chris Harshaw's answer is a much better (and more interesting) approach that works in far more generality. I'll keep my answer here in case there is something to be gained from it, but the other answer is superior in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Christian found all but one of the eigenvalues by showing that $A + 2I$ had nullity $n-1$ ($v_i = e_1 - e_i$ for $2 \leq i \leq n$ span the $2$-eigenspace.)

Also, when guessing in general for eigenvalues there are a few tricks that one gets used to when the matrix looks nice. One is looking for how to make a singular matrix by adding a multiple of the identity (as Christian did). Another is saying that all the entries of each row add to $2(n-1)$ so $v = [1 \cdots 1]^T$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $2n - 2$. If instead all the columns added to a fixed constant then that common value would also be a constant since a matrix is similar to its transpose.

So, the eigenvalues are $2n - 2$ and $-2$ with respective eigenvectors $v$ and $v_i$, $2 \leq i \leq n$.